# Hibernate. Is it better to catch exception or do extra check to prevent it?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have several `CheckBox` that have `Listener` on `selectedProperty`:

```
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue,
                            Boolean selected) {
        if (selected) {
            System.out.println(((Bank) checkBox.getUserData()).getName() + " is selected");
            FlatBankDA.save(currentFlat, (Bank)checkBox.getUserData());
        } else {
            FlatBankDA.delete(currentFlat, (Bank)checkBox.getUserData());
                        }}});
```

I create them once and then just switch between users. I read user data and change selection of `CheckBox` depending on which banks they have. Problem is when I change selection of `CheckBox` `Listener` is getting triggered, causing, for example, to delete connection that's not even there. What would be best practice to handle it? Catching exception that's getting thrown or doing an extra check before performing code?
This is how my `delete()` method looks:

```
public static void delete(Flat flat, Bank bank){
        Session sess = mainApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
         try {
             tx = sess.beginTransaction();

             CriteriaBuilder builder = sess.getCriteriaBuilder();

             //first check if connection already exists
             CriteriaQuery<FlatBank> query = builder.createQuery(FlatBank.class);
             Root<FlatBank> rootQuery = query.from(FlatBank.class);
             query.select(rootQuery).where(builder.and(builder.equal(rootQuery.get("flat"), flat), builder.equal(rootQuery.get("bank"), bank)));
             List<FlatBank> connection = sess.createQuery(query).getResultList();

             if(connection.size()>0){
                 CriteriaDelete<FlatBank> delete = builder.createCriteriaDelete(FlatBank.class);
                 Root<FlatBank> root = delete.from(FlatBank.class);
                 delete.where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("bank"), bank),builder.equal(root.get("flat"), flat)));
                 sess.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate(); 
             }

             tx.commit();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             System.out.println("Couldn't delete bank from flat "+flat.getNumber());
         }
         finally {
             sess.close();
         }
    }
```

Errors thrown:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1441)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:491)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at home.accounting.DA.FlatBankDA.save(FlatBankDA.java:58)
    at home.accounting.view.FlatInfoController$8.changed(FlatInfoController.java:632)
    at home.accounting.view.FlatInfoController$8.changed(FlatInfoController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.scene.control.CheckBox.setSelected(CheckBox.java:156)
    at javafx.scene.control.CheckBox.fire(CheckBox.java:236)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY]  A PRIMARY KEY constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: flat_bank.flat_id, flat_bank.bank_id)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:825)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:863)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: Each user should have their own `CheckBoxes`. Also its better to perform the check first, because it reduces execution time and you wont have to handle the exception

Comment: Because I can have thousands of users I render `CheckBoxes` first and then reuse them. Thanks, XtremeBaumer, I didn't know that check would work faster than catching exception) By the way, is there any way I could test situations like that? For example, some addon for Eclipse that would show performance for different scenarios?

Comment: You need to perform proper benchmarks for that, but if you think about it, then its obvious in this case. If you have the same code in an IF-ELSE and an TRY-CATCH, then the IF will not run if the check is not passed, while the try will always run